# How to search Twitter?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I need a PHP script that uses the Twitter API to obtain the following information: the number of unique tweets (or status updates) from a specific user (using their twitter username) containing a specific hashtag during a specific period of time.

I need that value to be the only returned data from calling that function/script; as well as the customizable lines of code containing all relevant values that I need to fill (app id, secret, username to obtain info from, etc).

Comment: Twitter provides links to a number of libraries for using their API in a variety of languages included PHP.  You may have to write some wrapper code to filter the returned info to exactly what you want but you can't expect people to do everything for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework has a nice Twitter API lib, which can be used standalone:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Comment: Zend is really overkill for a simple search API call. Two lines of straight PHP will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do with Twitter's Search API.

This is a JSON feed (just fetch with [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or `file_get_contents()` and parse with `json_decode()`) of my Twitter posts that include the `#fb` hashtag: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+%23fb+from%3Aceejayoz